# Cannot get mat-option selected value from mat-autocomplete using async

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, angular-material

I try to retrieve the whole object that is in each option of the mat-autocomplete's mat-option.

The optionSelected method does not return anything when I click on a mat-option. I also tried to add a click method on the mat-option but had the same results.

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
<mat-form-field>

  <input [formControl]="autoCompleteControl"
         [matAutocomplete]="auto"
         type="text"
         placeholder="Pick one"
         (keyup.enter)="submitPlayer1($event)"
         aria-label="Number"
         matInput>

  <mat-icon
    style="cursor: pointer"
    matSuffix>done_outline
  </mat-icon>

  <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectionChanged($event)">

    <mat-option *ngFor="let player of playersAutoComplete$ | async; let index = index"
                [value]="player">{{player}}>
      <img
        [src]="this.store.AVATAR_URL + player.pid + '.jpg'"
        class="example-option-img"
        aria-hidden height="25">
      <span>{{player.playerName}}</span> |
      <span class="text-info">{{player.leagueName}}</span> |
      <small>Population: {{player.teamName}}</small>
    </mat-option>

  </mat-autocomplete>

</mat-form-field>
```

I suspect that is the async which converts the observable to an array, but I cannot use directly an array, because I retrieve the auto-complete mat-option from an API.

Comment: I'll try to create one but it's a little bit complex right now. Have you experienced this issue before? I have implemented something like this, without async (just *ngFor = let player of players) and it works fine

Comment: Are you getting any error while using async pipe?

Comment: No errors. The mat-options shows fine with all the information I ask. But, the mat-option methods, either is a click inside it, either optionSelected in the mat-auto-complete, behave like there's no method called.

Comment: Woo It's strange If it's possible create stackblitz.

Comment: I found the error. I was using a duplicate input value and, maybe, there was a conflict with the form-control. Thanks